# Как добавить событие на клик в Toggle Menu?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Как сделать так, чтобы при клике на пункт меню сработало событие закрытия этого меню?

Событие открытия работает, а закрытие - нет!

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    
}

function closeNav2() {
    document.getElementById("about").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 12px;
   
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
  
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

</head>

<body>

<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#" id="about" onclick="closeNav2()">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ты ширину меняешь пункту меню, а не всему меню.

```js
function openNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
    
}

function closeNav2() {
    /*document.getElementById("about").style.width = "0";*/
    document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Почему `document.getElementById("about")`?

```js
function openNav() {
  console.log("openNav");
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  console.log("closeNav");
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}

function closeNav2() {
  console.log("closeNav2");
  document.getElementById("mySidenav").style.width = "0";
}
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lato", sans-serif;
}

.sidenav {
    height: 100%;
    width: 0;
    position: fixed;
    z-index: 1;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #111;
    overflow-x: hidden;
    transition: 0.5s;
    padding-top: 60px;
}

.sidenav a {
    padding: 1px 1px 1px 12px;
   
    font-size: 21px;
    color: #818181;
    display: block;
  
}

.sidenav a:hover {
    color: #f1f1f1;
}

.sidenav .closebtn {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 25px;
    font-size: 36px;
    margin-left: 50px;
}

@media screen and (max-height: 450px) {
  .sidenav {padding-top: 15px;}
  .sidenav a {font-size: 18px;}
}
```

```html
<div id="mySidenav" class="sidenav">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">&times;</a>
  <a href="#" id="about" onclick="closeNav2()">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<h2>Animated Sidenav Example</h2>
<p>Click on the element below to open the side navigation menu.</p>
<span style="font-size:30px;cursor:pointer" onclick="openNav()">&#9776; open</span>
```